# How to create array structure of div my matching div id with data-id which is id of other child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

```js
var pushData = [];
$(function() {
  CreateArray();
});


function CreateArray() {
  //output in data:
  var data = [{
    "Id": 38,
    "Connections": [39, 40],
    "Name": "ABc"
  }, {
    "Id": 39,
    "Connections": [40],
    "Name": "pqr"
  }, {
    "Id": 40,
    "Connections": [],
    "Name": "lmn"
  }];


  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $(document.createElement('div')).addClass("latestblock")
      .html(value.Name)
      .attr('id', value.Id)
      .attr('data-id', value.Connections)
      .appendTo($("#container"));
  });

  //Above loops generates this:
  //<div id="38" class="latestblock" data-id="39,40">ABc</div>
  //<div id="39" class="latestblock" data-id="40">pqr</div>
  //<div id="40" class="latestblock" data-id="">lmn</div>

  //Here data-id:39,40 indicated that div 39 and div 40 are connected to div 38 and so i want to create my array
  //like this:

  //Expected Output:
  //  pushData[0]:
  //   from:  <div id="38" class="latestblock" data-id="39,40">ABc</div>
  //   To:   <div id="39" class="latestblock" data-id="40">pqr</div>

  //  pushData[1]:
  //    from:  <div id="38" class="latestblock" data-id="39,40">ABc</div>
  //   To:   <div id="40" class="latestblock" data-id="">lmn</div>

  //  pushData[2]:
  //   from:  <div id="39" class="latestblock" data-id="40">pqr</div>
  // To:   <div id="40" class="latestblock" data-id="">lmn</div>


  //$('#container').find('div').each(function () {
  //    var Id = $(this).attr('id');
  //    var connections = $(this).attr('data-id').split(',');
  //    for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
  //       pushData.push({
  //            from: userId,
  //            to: connections[i]
  //        });
  //    }
  //    console.log(pushData)
  //});

  //With above code i am getting output like this:
  // pushData[0]:
  // from:38
  // To:39
  // pushData[0]:
  // from:38
  // To:40

}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  ertertert
</div>
```

I want to create `array structure` of div by matching `data-id`(which is comma seperated and this `data-id` is nothing but id of other `child divs`)
along with other div id:

This is my div:

```
<div id="container">
 </div>

var pushData = [];
function CreateArray(){
 $.getJSON('My Wcf service Url', function (data) {

          //output in data:
          var data=[
           {
              "Id": 38,
               Connections":[39,40],
                   "Name":"ABc"
          },
           {
              "Id": 39,
               Connections":[40],
               "Name":"pqr"
           },
           {
               "Id": 40,
                Connections":[],
               "Name":"lmn"
           }]


               $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $(document.createElement('div')).addClass("latestblock")
                    .html(value.Name)
                    .attr('id', value.Id)
                    .attr('data-id', value.Connections)
                    .appendTo($("#container"));
                });

               //Above loops generates this:
                  //<div id="38" class="latestblock" data-id="39,40">ABc</div>
                  //<div id="39" class="latestblock" data-id="40">pqr</div>
                  //<div id="40" class="latestblock" data-id="">lmn</div>

                 //Here data-id:39,40 indicated that div 39 and div 40 are connected to div 38 and so i want to create my array
                 //like this:

                 Expected Output:
                 pushData[0]:
                             from:  <div id="38" class="latestblock" data-id="39,40">ABc</div>
                              To:   <div id="39" class="latestblock" data-id="40">pqr</div>

                 pushData[1]:
                             from:  <div id="38" class="latestblock" data-id="39,40">ABc</div>
                             To:   <div id="40" class="latestblock" data-id="">lmn</div>

                 pushData[2]:
                             from:  <div id="39" class="latestblock" data-id="40">pqr</div>
                              To:   <div id="40" class="latestblock" data-id="">lmn</div>


        //$('#container').find('div').each(function () {
        //    var Id = $(this).attr('id');
        //    var connections = $(this).attr('data-id').split(',');
        //    for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
        //       pushData.push({
        //            from: userId,
        //            to: connections[i]
        //        });
        //    }
        //    console.log(pushData)
        //});

        //With above code i am getting output like this:
        pushData[0]:
                   from:38
                   To:39
        pushData[0]:
                   from:38
                   To:40
 });
}
```

**Expected Output**:

```
 pushData[0]:
                         from:  <div id="38" class="latestblock" data-id="39,40">ABc</div>
                              To:   <div id="39" class="latestblock" data-id="40">pqr</div>

                pushData[1]:
                            from:  <div id="38" class="latestblock" data-id="39,40">ABc</div>
                             To:   <div id="40" class="latestblock" data-id="">lmn</div>

                pushData[2]:
                             from:  <div id="39" class="latestblock" data-id="40">pqr</div>
                              To:   <div id="40" class="latestblock" data-id="">lmn</div>
```

Comment: Please keep your problem statement outside the code, and show the bare minimum code to reproduce your problem.  It is hard to help when your code is not even valid JavaScript.  You don't need to match data-id; they are strings, not array; just use your json data directly in the loop.

Comment: @Sheepy:I have created demo for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments inline in the code.

```
// The resulting array
var result = [];

// Iterate over all the objects in array
data.forEach(function (obj) {
    // Create the `from` object
    var from = $('<div id="' + obj.Id + '" class="latestblock" data-id="' + obj.Connections + '">' + obj.Name + '</div>');

    // Iterate over all connections of this item
    obj.Connections.forEach(function (id) {
        // Get the corr. data from the main array
        var connectionObj = data.find(obj => obj.Id === id),
            to = $('<div id="' + id + '" class="latestblock" data-id="' + connectionObj.Connections + '">' + connectionObj.Name + '</div>');

        // Add the object in the result array
        result.push({from, to});
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

[**Demo on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/o29tfg0p/1/)